# How to make a contact "group admin" of WhatsApp Group?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I guess with new version of WhatsApp Application, for a WhatsApp group, it is possible to have more than 1 "**Group Admin**".

My question is, if I am currently the Admin of one of the group and I wants to add one more member(or 2 or 3) of Same group as "Group Admin", what steps I need to follow?

Secondly, does WhatsApp imposes any Limit on no. of Group Admins per group?

For example: If WhatsApp Group has 10 People, how many of them can be "Group Admin"??